# How to detect whether a signal is unimodal or bimodal?

Tags: histogram, time-series

I have to kinds of signals. The first type of signals are such that their histograms are unimodal (one-peaked). The second type of signals are such that their histograms are bimodal (two-peaked). How I can best detect whether a signal is unimodal or bimodal? In some signals there is a lot of noise so the detection is going to be difficult I guess. Any ideas on how to measure "bimodalism"?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers to a similar question over on [Cross Validated.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51085/161).

One suggested answer is to use Hartigan's dip test. [Another is to use the `mixtools` package.](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-the-r-package-mixtools/)

I've simulated some example data in **R** and used [the `diptest` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diptest/index.html) and the `mixtools` package.  The diagram below shows the raw data in the top to graphs, and the estimated underlying distributions according to `mixtools`.

[image]

The `diptest` results are:

> data:  one_mode
>   D = 0.0219, p-value = 0.9915
>
> data:  two_mode
>   D = 0.0628, p-value = 0.004434

So `diptest` is saying the first (unimodal) data set has a 99.15% chance of being unimodal and the second (bimodal) data set has a 0.44% chance of being unimodal.

---

**R Code Below**
    # Q26358

```
one_mode <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
two_mode <- c(rnorm(50, -2, 1), rnorm(50, +2, 1))

plot(1:100,one_mode,pch=16, col="green")
lines(1:100,two_mode, pch=16, col="red")

library(mixtools)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(1:100,one_mode,pch=16, col="green")
plot(1:100,two_mode, pch=16, col="red")


mixmdl = normalmixEM(one_mode)
plot(mixmdl,which=2)
lines(density(one_mode), lty=2, lwd=2)

mixmdl_two = normalmixEM(two_mode)
plot(mixmdl_two,which=2)
lines(density(two_mode), lty=2, lwd=2)

library(diptest)
dip.test(one_mode)
dip.test(two_mode)
```